# React js: Passing API data down to child component in props. Can console.log props but can not render the data

Tags: reactjs, api

I have been trying to get familiar with React.  I have two components.  The API call is being made on the parent component and I'm trying to pass the data down to the child component.

This is my parent component:

```
export default function LandingPage(props) {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts").then((response) => {
      setPosts(response.data);
    });
  }, []);

  const classes = useStyles();
  const { ...rest } = props;
  return (
    <div>

      <div className={classNames(classes.main, classes.mainRaised)}>
        <div className={classes.container}>

          {/* HERE IS THE CHILD COMPONENT BELOW */}
          <ProductSection posts={posts} /> 

        </div>
      </div>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}
```

This is my Child component:

```
export default function ProductSection(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.section}>
      {/* HERE IS THE CONSOLE LOG */}
      {console.log(props.posts[0])}
      {/* HERE IS THE RENDER  */}
      <Typography>{props.posts[0]}</Typography>
   </div>

  );
}

ProductSection.propTypes = {
  posts: PropTypes.arrayOf(
    PropTypes.shape({
      userId: PropTypes.number,
      id: PropTypes.number,
      title: PropTypes.string,
      body: PropTypes.string,
    })
  ),
};
```

Thanks in advance, kinda new to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is object, it would be more clear if typography component is shared.
Although I tried solving it without the Typography and its working after adding conditional for the non existing postData as data will be fetched and will wait for promise to serve.
It is working.

App.js -> Parent

ProductSection.js -> Child

Refer this sandbox which will help you with code.
See this sandbox to get more clarity:

[LINK](https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-visvesvaraya-fjwm7?file=/src/ProductSection.js)

Comment: Thank you I have the displaying now,  I was wondering if you could maybe explain a little more about what is happening here, I'm still struggling to figure it out.  THanks you

Comment: 2. When making a network request , there is latency. i.e. it will take some time to load the data. So react will render initallly and it will expect something in the state. Just imagine the loading concept. There should be some loading state. So we set postData to something falsy. So that we can add conditional and wait for data. When data comes we set the state and remember whenever we set state. React rerenders, so it will populate data now before that it will not because its a ( network request get axios ) which has latency and initially react expects something.

Comment: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/fetch-data-react/#:~:text=The%20most%20accessible%20way%20to,very%20easily%20using%20JavaScript%20promises. Refer this for more clarity , very well explained here

Comment: 1. React cannot render an object. It cannot implicitly but explicitly by converting with stringifying it we can. But why to render an object. We would definitely want to show its keys like id, title or body. So for example child component got an object which was in your code : props.posts[0]. So we will access its keys because react can implicitly render string or number . So we access its keys. So object render problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

I guess probably your data in props.posts[0] is object, so I would try with JSON.stringify(props.posts[0],null,2).